# Can an old CHM file be updated to work with Windows 10?

Tags: c++, chm

I am using the Windows 10 Enterprise OS.  I have a help file in CHM format that cannot be opened in a Windows 10 box.  All it says is "Failed to launch help."  I wrote a tiny program to try this.  Here's the important bit of code:

```
void CHelpFileTEstDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CWinApp* pApp = AfxGetApp();
    AfxMessageBox(pApp->m_pszHelpFilePath);
    pApp->m_pszHelpFilePath = _T("C:\\Dev\\LD\\RSLogix5000\\BuildProducts\\Debug\\PSModuleENU.chm");

    AfxMessageBox(_T("Does this help button work?"), MB_YESNO | MB_HELP | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, 196743);
}
```

When I click the Help button, I get the same "Failed to launch help." message, but also, a web page appears in my browser saying that help system I'm using is not support in Windows 10.  Here's [that link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-opening-help-in-windows-based-programs-feature-not-included-or-help-not-supported-3c841463-d67c-6062-0ee7-1a149da3973b).

I had already asked a [question in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74392242/1981088) a day before (see also for further information).

Is there a tool I can use to modernize the CHM file to make it usable on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

When CHM Help Files showing up blank in windows 10.

Do the next:

**Find the .chm file location, right click, and go to properties and check "Unblock" and apply**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a CHM help file that did not work on Windows 10.

The [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-opening-help-in-windows-based-programs-feature-not-included-or-help-not-supported-3c841463-d67c-6062-0ee7-1a149da3973b) you mentioned points to an even older help system namely WinHelp with the .hlp file extension.

This help system has not been supported for a long time. Only extensive steps still allowed to open *.hlp WinHelp files some time ago (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643026/1981088).

There may be a confusion between WinHelp (*.hlp) and HTMLHelp (*.chm). To test this, copy your help file into a local directory and double click on it. The file must then be opened and displayed in a help window under Windows 10.

AFAIK - you'll not need a tool to modernize a CHM file for use under Windows 10.

FYI - I remember some old stuff [Connecting HTML Help to C++/MFC Programs](http://www.smountain.com/resource/CPPHTMLHelp.pdf)

Comment: Double-clicking the help file opens it with no problem.  I just can't set up an application to use a help topic within my help file through AfxMessageBox().  Given the code above, can you think of a reason why not?

Comment: Is there a way to get further information on why help could not be launched?  I can't tell if the context ID isn't found or the entire help file isn't found or some other error happened.

Comment: I am not an experienced C++ programmer. I added the C++ tag to your question and also a reference to your previous question.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON double-clicking in Explorer simply opens the file in the associated application (HTMLhelp in this case); surely it is a matter of doing the same programmatically via `ShellExecute` for example?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115574/how-can-you-open-a-file-with-the-program-associated-with-its-file-extension

Comment: I am trying to debug an application that uses AfxMessageBox().  Therefore, I need to know why AfxMessageBox() is failing for this particular file.  ShellExecute() is not an option.